# MS Dynamics CRM - Odata Query and Using $expand

Tags: javascript, html, odata, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I will try to be as clear as possible.

I have three entities -- 1. "Event" 2. "Event Category" and 3. "Questions"

Each "Event" record has an "Event Category" field. "Event Category" has a 1:N relationship to the "Questions" entity. Each question record has an "Event Category" field. On load of an event form, I have a JS web resource that gets the GUID of the "Event Category" for that particular event.

Using an html web resource, I want to return all questions that have the same "Event Category" as the "Event" page I'm currently on. I'm having trouble determining how to build the correct odata query string.

I believe I am close, but the final step eludes me. Please see my code to build the URL below (I didn't include the rest of retrieveMultiple, just the URL build):

```
function getEventQuestions () {
var eventCatId = getEventCatId();
retrieveMultiple("new_eventcategorySet(guid'" + eventCatId + "')", "?$expand=new_new_eventcategory_new_questions"**, showQuestions, null, null);
} 
function retrieveMultiple(odataSetName, filter, successCallback, errorCallback, _executionObj) {
var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
var ODATA_ENDPOINT = "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc";
var odataUri = serverUrl + ODATA_ENDPOINT + "/" + odataSetName;
if (filter) {
odataUri += filter;
}
```

I believe this will return all question records related to the GUID of the event category for the event I'm on. 
How do I further refine my search so I can print the questions themselves using my html web resource? If I use $select to return certain properties, it'll return properties of the Event Category set, and not the questions set, as I desire. 
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.